# How to get labels to diplay in Google Earth after saving to KML?

Tags: qgis, kml, labeling

When saving a QGIS layer as kml, is it possible to have labels be displayed when opened in Google Earth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the shapefile's DBF the labels have to be in a column headed "name" (without the quotes). I don't think case is important, you could use "name", "Name" or "NAME". N.

Comment: Naming column doesn't do what is asked. This is somehow related to XML-shema. In current Google maps there is also description which should be added to QGIS-generated KML-file. Now if you view your KML in map it doesn't have name or description. Only symbol on the left side layer list.